# SQL Pivot creates NULL instead of merging on DateTime value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

My raw data looks like this:

```
value   InsertedAt  timestamp   country model   ForecastRun origin  ID
10  2019-10-16 19:06:05.793 2019-10-11 21:00:00.000 Germany fundamentalmodel    3D8 manual  1065
10  2019-10-16 19:06:05.793 2019-10-11 22:00:00.000 Germany fundamentalmodel    3D8 manual  1066
10  2019-10-16 19:06:05.793 2019-10-11 23:00:00.000 Germany fundamentalmodel    3D8 manual  1067
13  2019-10-16 19:06:07.240 2019-10-11 21:00:00.000 France  fundamentalmodel    3D8 manual  1089
13  2019-10-16 19:06:07.240 2019-10-11 22:00:00.000 France  fundamentalmodel    3D8 manual  1090
13  2019-10-16 19:06:07.240 2019-10-11 23:00:00.000 France  fundamentalmodel    3D8 manual  1091
```

I want to pivot based on the column 'country'.

This is my query:

```
SELECT timestamp, Germany, France
FROM dbo.Forecasts
PIVOT (
 AVG(value)
 FOR country IN (
    [Germany],
    [France])
) as pivot_table
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

My expected outcome is:

```
timestamp   Germany France
2019-10-11 23:00:00.000 10  13
2019-10-11 22:00:00.000 10  13
2019-10-11 21:00:00.000 10  13
```

My actual outcome is:

```
timestamp   Germany France
2019-10-11 23:00:00.000 10  NULL
2019-10-11 23:00:00.000 NULL    13
2019-10-11 22:00:00.000 NULL    13
2019-10-11 22:00:00.000 10  NULL
2019-10-11 21:00:00.000 10  NULL
2019-10-11 21:00:00.000 NULL    13
```

I tried my query on different data and it works fine. However, not in this particular case. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table dbo.Forecasts
(
  value int not null,
  InsertedAt datetime not null,
  [timestamp] datetime not null,
  country varchar(100) not null,
  model varchar(100) not null,
  ForecastRun varchar(100) not null,
  origin varchar(100) not null,
  ID int not null
)
GO

insert into dbo.Forecasts
(value,InsertedAt,[timestamp],country,model,ForecastRun,origin,ID)
values
(10, '2019-10-16 19:06:05.793', '2019-10-11 21:00:00.000', 'Germany', 'fundamentalmodel', '3D8', 'manual',  1065)
,(10, '2019-10-16 19:06:05.793', '2019-10-11 22:00:00.000', 'Germany', 'fundamentalmodel', '3D8', 'manual',  1066)
,(10, '2019-10-16 19:06:05.793', '2019-10-11 23:00:00.000', 'Germany', 'fundamentalmodel', '3D8', 'manual',  1067)
,(13, '2019-10-16 19:06:07.240', '2019-10-11 21:00:00.000', 'France', 'fundamentalmodel', '3D8', 'manual',  1089)
,(13, '2019-10-16 19:06:07.240', '2019-10-11 22:00:00.000', 'France', 'fundamentalmodel', '3D8', 'manual',  1090)
,(13, '2019-10-16 19:06:07.240', '2019-10-11 23:00:00.000', 'France', 'fundamentalmodel', '3D8', 'manual',  1091)
GO


SELECT pt.[timestamp], pt.[Germany], pt.[France]
FROM (select f.value, f.[timestamp], f.country from dbo.Forecasts f) as x
PIVOT (
 AVG(x.value)
 FOR x.country IN (
    [Germany],
    [France])
) as pt
ORDER BY pt.[timestamp] DESC
GO
```

Results in

```
timestamp               Germany     France
----------------------- ----------- -----------
2019-10-11 23:00:00.000 10          13
2019-10-11 22:00:00.000 10          13
2019-10-11 21:00:00.000 10          13

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Where was the problem?

`FROM dbo.Forecasts`

Can be instead:

`FROM (select f.value, f.[timestamp], f.country from dbo.Forecasts f) as x`

You must list all columns that will participate in the aggregate, but no more that it.
The `ID` column was messing with the aggregate, making each row in the source table put a value in the result. If you add `f.ID` in the select you will reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see. I did not know that. Well I am rather glad it was not just a stupid typo.

Answer (score 0):

the same sql you are using works fine for me in Oracle DB

```
with aa as (select 10 value, '2019-10-11 21:00:00.000' timestamp, 'Germany' country     
from dual union all
select 10 value, '2019-10-11 22:00:00.000' timestamp, 'Germany' country from dual     union all
select 10 value, '2019-10-11 23:00:00.000' timestamp, 'Germany' country from dual     union all
select 13 value, '2019-10-11 21:00:00.000' timestamp, 'France' country from dual     union all
select 13 value, '2019-10-11 22:00:00.000' timestamp, 'France' country from dual     union all
select 14 value, '2019-10-11 23:00:00.000' timestamp, 'France' country from dual
)
SELECT *
FROM aa
PIVOT (
 AVG(value)
 FOR country IN (
    'Germany',
    'France'))  pivot_table
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: OP, select included ID as a source column, just removing it can fix the problem. I'm curious if you add ID can cause the same behavior in Oracle (I bet yes!)